# Remove Cloudfront, redirect CNAME links to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

My Cloudfront costs have exploded from $400/month to $2,000/month and I'd like to stop using it, however I don't want the urls for our custom domain to stop working.

What's the best way to redirect those urls to the S3 origin?
i.e. sub.domain.com/s3-object automatically requests s3bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/s3-object?

Comment: Your bucket name needs to match the domain name. See: [Example: Setting Up a Static Website Using a Custom Domain - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I was able to continue to use my custom Cloudfront domain and remove the Cloudfront cost:

1. Allocate new elastic IP
2. Associate elastic IP with private IP
3. Create new web app (using PHP/Laravel 4.2)

3a. sudo composer create-project
     laravel/laravel eterna 4.2 --prefer-dist

3b. create catch all route to redirect to S3

```
App::missing(function($exception)

{
   $path = Request::path();

   return Redirect::to('https://mybuckey.s3.amazonaws.com/' . $path);

});
```

4. Create Apache virtual host referencing private IP.
5. Update Route 53 to point to new elastic IP instead of cloudfrount distribution

Saved myself up to $25,000/year in 30 minutes.

Comment: You have almost certainly overlooked an explanation for the costs that could have been discovered in the CloudFront logs -- massive popularity, malicious/unauthorized activity, or a bug in your code causing unnecessary traffic -- because using CloudFront with S3 typically costs about the same as using S3 alone, and sometimes costs less depending on the location of the bucket and the location of the viewer.  Using CloudFront dramatically lowers your S3 bill, so this change is likely to simply shift those costs back to S3 since it appeara from the question that you have not identified the cause.

Comment: Sounds like a good case for activating [logging in CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/AccessLogs.html) and [in S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html) to identify the cause of the traffic.